# dotnetnuke up and running error

Tags: dotnetnuke

I developed a DotNetNuke application and hosted it on a web server. When I browse the site, I am getting the following error:

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Runtime Error  Description: An
>   application error occurred on the
>   server. The current custom error
>   settings for this application prevent
>   the details of the application error
>   from being viewed remotely (for
>   security reasons). It could, however,
>   be viewed by browsers running on the
>   local server machine.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this
>   specific error message to be viewable
>   on remote machines, please create a
>   `<customErrors>` tag within a
>   "web.config" configuration file
>   located in the root directory of the
>   current web application. This
>   `<customErrors>` tag should then have
>   its "mode" attribute set to "Off".
>
> ```
> <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
>
> <configuration>
>     <system.web>
>         <customErrors mode="Off"/>
>     </system.web> </configuration>
> ```
>
> Notes: The current error page you are
>   seeing can be replaced by a custom
>   error page by modifying the
>   "defaultRedirect" attribute of the
>   application's `<customErrors>`
>   configuration tag to point to a custom
>   error page URL.
>
> ```
> <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
>
> <configuration>
>     <system.web>
>         <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"
>          defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
>     </system.web> </configuration>
> ```

Can any one tell me how to resolve the problem...

Comment: Thank you for your cooperation

Answer (score 4):

The main problem here is that you aren't getting any detail about what the error. Any success achieved while troubleshooting this without exposing some more detail (or knowledge of your setup) is going to be pretty close to pure luck.

I would suggest following the instructions that this default error message is giving you and editing the web. config file. The file is named "web.config" and it lives in the root of the website.

Open the file and search for "RemoteOnly", you should see something that says customErrors mode="RemoteOnly". Change the "RemoteOnly" to "Off" and save the file. The next time you browse to the site you should see a more detailed error message. Please share that with us here in the form of an update to your current post or as a new question (which I recommend, as it technically will be a different question).

Also, I recommend making a backup copy of the web.config file first before making any changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if your ASP.NET is functional. Since you didnt post any details on your web server, i would recommend you check if you have .NET 2.0 installed and your web server is configured to use it.

You can run aspnet_regiis -i in the c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.x.x.x. directory to re-register the aspnet modules.

You might also want to check if your virtual directories have the execute permission enabled.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you "developed a DotNetNuke application" I need more information.

Did you develop a DotNetNuke MODULE?

If so, did you install it on a DotNetNuke site that was working before, but isn't now?